# using mac address in filepath - file not found?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, object

```
$test = @(gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration | select macaddress ) 
$test | ForEach-Object {

Write-Host $_.macaddress
$mac = $_.macaddress -replace ":", ""
$mac.Trim()
If (Test-Path "x:\$Mac") { $computer = $mac }

$Logfile = "x:\$Computer\$Computer.Log"
$File = "x:\$computer\$computer.ini"
$computer
$CompName = Get-Content $File | Select-Object -index 0
}
```

So the above script will not find the $file even though it is present. The x:\64006A849B90\64006A849B90.ini is present but i get this

ERROR: Get-Content : Cannot find path 'X:\64006A849B90\64006A849B90.ini' because it does not exist.

Anyone know why i cant use this - i know its something to do with the $mac value and making sure its a string but i have tried $mac.ToString() [String]$mac and trimming it and it will not see the path - any ideas? thanks

The strange thing is the value is being picked up hence the mac address being in the path but it wont find the path if that makes sense.

Comment: So if you run this you see the file in the results? `Get-ChildItem "X:\64006A849B90"`

Comment: Hi Matt if i run this Get-ChildItem "X:\$computer" i get the content of X:\ not x:\64006A849B90 if i run gci x:\64006A849B90 it works but i that value has to be a variable - its something with this  $computer = $mac - but i cant work it out

Comment: So `$computer` is null then. That is set based on the result of this `Test-Path "x:\$Mac"`. What happens if you run that _not_ in the if but just as I typed it. Does it return false? I suspect it does and that is why `$computer` is null. That being said I do not know what you bother changing the name of the variable. Why not just keep using `$mac`?

Comment: returns True - confused.. if i test path x:\$computer it returns false. so the $computer = $mac is not taking -

Comment: depends where you are testing that. Are you trying _after_ the if statement? Also, this should not matter because it should have no effect, you use `.trim()` on $mac but do not save it back so if that is needed you should `$mac=$mac.trim()` (code could use a cleaning though fyi).

Comment: OH...... You should have a bunch of empty macs there as well. Those were create nulls. Do all of your adapters have MACs? What is your `$test.count`

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have other issues but assuming your files are named and exist where you expect the only problem you would have to deal with is potential nulls.

Do you have any adapters that do no have MAC Addresses? I have 3 right now. Using your code it will attempt to process those. If you were not aware of those I could see that being an issue. Easy to fix will a small code update

```
# Get the populated macs from all network adapters
$macs = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration | Select-Object -ExpandProperty macaddress

ForEach($mac in $macs){
    $mac = $mac.replace(":","")
    $macFile = "x:\$mac\$mac.ini"
    if(Test-Path $macFile){
        # The ini file exists 
        $computer = Get-Content $macFile | Select-Object -Index 0
    } else {
        # Cant find the file
    }

    $computer
}
```

This could be simplified even further but I didn't want to do too much at once.

By using `Select-Object -ExpandProperty macaddress` we still get nulls but they are dropped by the pipeline so `$macs` would only contain strings of actual MACs.

The whole `$computer = $mac` should have worked but it was redundant so I removed that logic from your code.